# jQuery XML Parsing - Return Parent Elements Of Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to return the parent element when searching for a child element and then display a parallel child's text.

XML:

```
<store>
    <shelf>
        <book>
            <name>Book_1</name>
            <id>1</id>
        </book>
        <book>
            <name>Book_2</name>
            <id>2</id>
        </book>
        <book>
            <name>Book_1</name>
            <id>3</id>
        </book>
    </shelf>
</store>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml_file.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml){

    var books = $(xml).find('name').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === 'Book_1';
    }).parent();

    for(i=0; i<books.length; i++){
        $('#results').text(
            (books[i]).find('id').text()
        );
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

So basically, if I search for a "name" with that has text "book", I want to get back 2 books. Than I want to display each book to a div with id="results". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you host the xml some where or give the url of  sample xml to use ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is invalid, you're missing a root node, and `</aid>` should be `</id>` like

```
<shelf>
    <book>
        <name>Book_1</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Book_2</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Book_1</name>
        <id>3</id>
    </book>
</shelf>
```

Also you're missing a `$` in praseXml and using .text will over write all previous values

```
function parseXml(xml){

    var books = $(xml).find('name').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === 'Book_1';
    }).parent();

    for(i=0; i<books.length; i++){
        $('#results').append(
            $(books[i]).find('id').text()
        );
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uq9cW/

Comment: I updated the example XML in the original question. This worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting your xml into a local variable for brevity.

```
var $xml = $("<books><book><name>Book_1</name><id>1</aid></book><book><name>Book_2</name><id>2</aid></book><book>   <name>Book_1</name><id>3</aid></book></books>")

var searchString = "Book_1";
var matchedBooks = $xml
  .children('book')  /* Get all the books */
  .children('name')  /* And then the names. You could just get the names first, but this will allow you to exclude nodes not inside of a book element  */
  .filter(function(i,v){ return $(v).text() == searchString; })  /* This excludes non matching names. */
  .parent('book');  /* Now we have 2 matching elements, on each, get the parent element */

/* Build the html then append to save DOM interaction speed tax */
var resultHtml = "";
$(matchedBooks).each(function(i, e){
   resultHtml += "<p>" + $(e).find('id').text() + "</p>";
});
$("#results").html( resultHtml );
```

Let me know if that answers your question